# How to hide filtered column with dynamic data site?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have 'ProductType' column filtered, but it still is in data grid. If I apply ScaffoldColumn(false) filtering feature will disappear...

How to hide column and keep filtering option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need something like this :

```
[Display(Name = "Product Type", AutoGenerateFilter = true, AutoGenerateField = false)]
public object ProductType { get; set; }
```

Or, you'll need to extend the Metadata for that column.  Steve Naughton shows how [here](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/10/dynamic-data-hiding-columns-in-selected.html).